# How to create table by using div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table like this, but using div instead of table

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{ font-family:"Segoe UI", "Tahoma" }
    td {
        padding:0px 5px 10px 5px;
    }
    .username {
        white-space:nowrap;
        vertical-align:top;
        text-align:right;
        width:auto;
        color:DodgerBlue;
    }
    </style>

    <table width="500px" >
        <tr>
            <td class="username">copperfield</td>
            <td>How to create table by using div  </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top">time </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="username">copperfield</td> 
            <td>
              How to create table by using div How to create table by sing div How to create table by to create table by using div <img src="images/thinking.gif"> </br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top"> 8:00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="username"> </td> 
            <td>
               How to create table by using div</br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top"> 8:00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="username"> </td> 
            <td>
               How to create table by using div</br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top"> 8:00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="username">michael</td> <td><img src="images/thinking.gif"> Gi ku </td> 
            <td style="vertical-align:top"> 8:00 </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I try the following code but it is not successful

```
   <style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family:Segoe UI;
    }
    .all{

    float:left;
    display:block;
    }

    .chat{
    width:700px;
    float:left;
    display:table-cell;
    }

    .us{
        color:blue;
        text-align:right;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;

    }
    .ct{
    white-space:normal;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    .t{
        float:left;
        width:auto
    }
    </style>
    <div class="all">

    <div class="chat">
        <div class="us"> userna3 46346346me </div> 
        <div  class="ct"> content </div > 
        <div class="t"> time </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat">
        <div class="us"> copperfield </div> 
        <div class="ct"> How to create table by using div How to create table by sing div How to create table by to create table by using div</div> 
        <div class="t"> 8:00 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat">
        <div class="us"> copperfield </div> 
        <div  class="ct"> How to create table by using div Ho </div> 
        <div class="t"> 8:00 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Contrary to popular belief tables are not evil when used for, you know... table stuff.

Comment: you will need to lookup the css float property ( http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp )

Comment: What is the reason not to use a `<table>`? The code will be easier to create, understand and maintain.

Comment: @David Laberge:  I would vote down your comment if I could.  See [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com).

Comment: It's good to use a `table` when presenting data, I think this would be the perfect scenario for actually using one. However, if you're so opposed then please see my answer.

Comment: Please _DON'T REINVENT THE WHEEL!!_ Table tags exist for a reason: to present data that should be displayed in tables!

Comment: this is my execerise and I must convert the page from using table to div. Div is considered to better than table in html layout

Comment: `div` is considered to be a better tool for layout; `table` is better for storing tabular data (a price sheet, results of a test of any sort, the list goes on). If you're trying to re-create a table using `div`s, you're completely missing the point of avoiding tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ttunW/. The key was using `display:table;` for `.all`, `display:table-row;`, for `.chat`, getting rid of the `float:left` properties on all the `div`s, and assigning `display:table-cell;` to the `div`s within `.chat`.

Comment: No it doesn't. If it needs to work in IE, then a `<table>` should just be used, as would be semantically correct in this situation.

Comment: it doesnot work correctly. I want the page has a fix width  700px, the first column Name and column Time should have auto size and do not break line.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have something floating in a float. It just doesn't work in some ugly browsers *cough* IE *cough*.

So change your all class in your css to look like this:

```
.all div {float:left;}
```

Then take away all the other floats from your classes. For the us, ct, and t just give them a set width inside of each chat div. Also change the div's inside of the chat div's to p tags.

Comment: I don't think we should set width with fix size, because I want the width of column Name correspond to the text username.